# search on Enter not work jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a problem with my search function, when I use search on mouse click, it works perfect, but when I use search on Enter, not work first time when I search, but if I repeat the search on Enter for the same column it works.
So, when I search on Enter first time, it returns to me all the rows that don't have values in the column that I execute the search, and when I repeat, second time, the search action on Enter, it works perfect. I don't know why the search action has this strange behaviour.

jqGrid code: function for searchOnEnter:

```
var grid=$("#grid");

grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {
                add: false, edit: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: false
            })

grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
             title:"Search",
             buttonicon:"ui-icon-search",
             caption: "",
             onClickButton: function () {

            grid.searchGrid({jqModal : true, multipleSearch:true, closeAfterSearch:false, closeAfterReset: false, 
            closeOnEscape: true , searchOnEnter: true, recreateForm:true });

$("#searchcntfbox_grid").on( "keydown", function(event){ //id of search contain box

                if(event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER){
                    $(event.target).trigger("change");
        $('#fbox_grid_search').click();   // id of search/find button
        }

            });

}
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: Hi, Oleg. In jquery.jqGrid.js file I found: jqGrid  4.5.4 - jQuery Grid

Comment: The to verify the same by simple usage the standard `navGrid` and free jqGrid 4.13.1. It's the fork which I develop. Every program have some bugs. The bugs will be fixed, but it helps you not if you would use old buggy version.

Comment: Ok. I have a small problem, I can't change the jqGrid version. I must use this version: jqGrid 4.5.4. Can you give me a solution for this version?

Comment: I asked you to change URLs to jqGrid files described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). Is the problem exist? Do you see any compatibility problems?

Comment: I tried to implement the version from you, but my project crashes.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the goal of you posts. Do you want that somebody help you? Then you should provide the demo which uses non-minimized version of jqGrid and which one can debug to find the reason of the problem. Posting that you have some code which not works don't help nobody. Look at [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7gfhyxgw/6/) or [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7gfhyxgw/7/) if you prefer to use old jQuery UI icons. You can see that `searchOnEnter: true` works.

Comment: Sorry  Oleg for my comment, but I don't have rights to change the grid version in the project. I must use that version.  I appreciate that you help me with a lot of informations. Thanks.